# Firestore delete key within nested dictionary (map)

Tags: python, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to delete keys in a nested dictionary that have values of 0:

```
{
"keyA": {
        "keyA1": 10,
        "keyA2": 0,
        "keyA3": 3,
    },
"keyB": {
        "keyB1": 2,
        "keyB2": 6,
        "keyB3": 0,
    },
}
```

I've tried every combination using `.DELETE_FIELD`

```
database.collection("cases").document("ari_test").update({
        f"someMap": {
            "keyA": {
                database.field_path("keyA2"): firestore.DELETE_FIELD
            }

        }
    })
```

I get the error:

```
ValueError: Cannot update with nest delete: FieldPath('someMap','keyA','`keyA2`')
```

Do i need to `.get()` the whole dict, update it in python then overwrite the whole map on firestore?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a [path with dot-notation](https://googleapis.dev/python/firestore/latest/document.html#google.cloud.firestore_v1.document.DocumentReference.update) to update nested fields, for example:

```
database.collection('cases').document('ari_test').update({
        'someMap.keyA.keyA2': firestore.DELETE_FIELD
        })
```